# 2amigos widgets format "dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: date, datepicker, yii2

I use [datepicker](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) to create an input in a form.

I use like this :

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'DATE_BIRTH')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
    // inline too, not bad
    'inline' => true,
    // modify template for custom rendering
    'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',

    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'todayBtn' => true
    ]
]);
?>
```

But when insert into database, it gives me error coz incorrect value.
Mysql have a format "yyyy-mm-dd".

How can I still get my date format in datepicker, coz in Indonesia, we know 'dd-mm-yyyy' .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeSave` method in your model file to change the date format before saving into the database like below.

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {

//if you want only on insert you can use this if condition else remove the if condition.
if($insert){
   $this->DATE_BIRTH = Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime(strtotime($this->DATE_BIRTH), "php:Y-m-d");
}
   return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```